# Envoy proxy: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: docker, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

### State of Servies:

Client (`nuxt`) is up on `http://localhost:3000` and the client sends
requests to `http://localhost:8080`.

Server (`django`) is running on `0.0.0.0:50051`.

Also `docker` is up

```
78496fef541f   5f9773709483      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   29 minutes
 ago   Up 29 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080-8080/tcp,
 10000/tcp   envoy
```

---

### `envoy.yaml` Configurations:

I configured the `envoy.yaml` file as follows:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route:
                            cluster: greeter_service
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
    - name: greeter_service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 0.0.0.0
                      port_value: 50051
```

---

### **Error:**

But the following error occurs and, as it seems, the requests do not reach the Django `0.0.0.0:50051` server.

> **503 Service Unavailable**
>
> grpc-message: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before
> headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason:
> delayed connect error: 111

[image: chrome screenshot]

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address, so you can't send requests to it. 0.0.0.0 only makes sense on a server when you bind to a port, where it means that the server will accept connections from any IP address. Try http://localhost:8080/ instead.

Comment: @HansKilian I configured the file based on what was said [in the document](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld#configure-the-proxy).

Comment: OK. It's just that you write (in the first line of your post) that you make requests to http://0.0.0.0:8080/. The article you linked says (under 'Write client code') that you should make the request to http://localhost:8080/.

Comment: @HansKilian You are right. I made this change but still had the same error.

Comment: @HansKilian I resolved this problem using `nginx`. Please see my answer hear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417090/9422637

Comment: A very well written [article](https://nuvalence.io/insights/lessons-learned-investigating-goaways-in-grpc-apis/) about strange GoAway 503 occurrences in combination with a proxy (in that case an NGINX) helped me understand more about possible ssl hickups.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error. Here are my condition:

- Envoy: running on docker with listener at port 8080 and redirect to port 9090
- Next JS Web client: request to envoy proxy at port 8080
- Node Grpc Server: listen on port 9090

Im starting all on local environment.

Based on [this example about configuring the envoy proxy](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld#configure-the-proxy) that refer to [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/436), I change the address on envoy proxy to `host.docker.internal` on envoy.yaml.

Just refer to this section, if you want to try:

```
clusters:
  - name: backend_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster_0
      endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: host.docker.internal // i change it, before was 0.0.0.0
                    port_value: 9090
```

Comment: Windows or Mac, I had this problem on Linux.